# How to write ButtonStyle of ThemeExtention in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to create custom ButtonStyle ThemeExtention class in Flutter, so that can make various styled ElevatedButtons.

But I encountered 2 errors.

> 1.The argument type 'ButtonStyle?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ButtonStyle'
>
> 2.The parameter 'style' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

My code is as below:

```
class DecisionButtonStyle extends ThemeExtension<DecisionButtonStyle> {
  const DecisionButtonStyle({
    required this.style,
    //this.foregroundColor,
    //this.backgroundColor,
  });

  final ButtonStyle style;
  //final Color? backgroundColor;
  //final Color? foregroundColor;

  @override
  DecisionButtonStyle lerp(
      ThemeExtension<DecisionButtonStyle> other, double t) {
    if (other is! DecisionButtonStyle) {
      return this;
    }

    return DecisionButtonStyle(
      style: ButtonStyle.lerp(style, other.style, t), <== Error 1 Here
      //foregroundColor: Color.lerp(foregroundColor, other.foregroundColor, t),
      //backgroundColor: Color.lerp(backgroundColor, other.backgroundColor, t),

    );
  }

  @override
  DecisionButtonStyle copyWith({ButtonStyle style}) => DecisionButtonStyle( <==Error 2 Here
        style: style ?? this.style,
        //backgroundColor: backgroundColor ?? this.backgroundColor,
        //foregroundColor: foregroundColor ?? this.foregroundColor,
      );

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Or Is my approach wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself.

Both errors are solved with default value.

```
class DecisionButtonStyle extends ThemeExtension<DecisionButtonStyle> {
  const DecisionButtonStyle({
    required this.style,
  });

  final ButtonStyle style;

  @override
  DecisionButtonStyle lerp(
      ThemeExtension<DecisionButtonStyle> other, double t) {
    if (other is! DecisionButtonStyle) {
      return this;
    }

    return DecisionButtonStyle(
      style: ButtonStyle.lerp(style, other.style, t) ?? ButtonStyle(),

    );
  }

  @override
  DecisionButtonStyle copyWith({ButtonStyle style = const ButtonStyle()}) => DecisionButtonStyle(
        style: style ?? this.style,
      );

}
```